# Запуск web_сервера на FreeBSD

Tags: php, linux, ssh, freebsd

Имеется доступ к серверу на FreeBSD, подключение к нему происходит через ssh, на сервере лежат исходники приложения написанного на php, нужно запустить веб-сервер для этого приложения. Как это сделать используя только встроенный сервер на php?
То есть, я хочу запустить веб-сервер используя примерно команды для запуска сервера 'php -S localhost:4040' и далее в браузере использовать 'http://<server_ip>:4040', но все мои попытки были не верны.

Comment: Ну если вы пишете localhost, то вполне логично, что сервер будет доступен только локально, а не откуда-то извне

Comment: Я должен вместо localhost использовать текущий ip сервера? У меня так тоже не работает, если я конечно правильно использовал

Comment: Я говорю глупость, или всё-таки нужен на FreeBSD не только PHP, но и какой-нибудь веб-сервер? Ну, хотя бы тот же Apache?

Comment: А все имеющиеся межсетевые экраны разрешают обращение к порту 4040?

Comment: На локальном хосте нет службы, которая прослушивает порт 4040

Comment: Ну так а все имеющиеся межсетевые экраны проверяли?